# Trace what runs the function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

private function dataLevel():void {

```
        //Level 2
        a1=new Array(b1,b2);
        a2=new Array(b3,b4);


        //Level 1
        allA=new Array(a1,a2);


        //trace if the following level exist

        //if the following level exist, create the Branch
        if (allA is Array==true) {
            createBranch(this);

            if (allA[0] is Array==true) {
                createBranch(allA[0]);
            }

            if (allA[1] is Array==true) {
                createBranch(allA[1]);
            }
        }
    }


    private function createBranch(event:Object):void {

        trace(event.target);
```

}

Comment: well you see i have 3 condition that runs createBranch();

at the createBranch function i would like to know its run by which of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just naming a variable as *event* won't make it an `Event` object (and give it a target property). Use `trace(event);` to trace the passed parameter. Even better, change the variable name to arg1 (argument1) or something that makes more sense.

```
private function createBranch(arg1:Object):void 
{
    trace(arg1);
}
```

`event` is normally used for variables of type `Event` or its subclasses in an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are basically trying to get something along the lines of a stack trace.  You can get a string representation of the stack trace from the Error exception class at runtime, but only in debug mode in Flash Player.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29

```
private function createBranch(arg1:Object):void 
{
    var stacktrace:String = new Error().getStackTrace();
    //parse 'stacktrace' and do what you want here.
}
```

Now this only works in the **debug** versions of the player, 'getStackTrace()' returns null in the standard versions, so this would not work for any production app.

The only other alternative would be to pass a token in to 'createBranch' to indicate where the call came from (which I assume would also determine what type of 'branch' you're creating?)  This would be a better approach to keep you logic more clean as well I think:

```
private function createBranch(arg1:Object, branchType:String):void 
{
    switch(branchType){
        case "type1":
             //create your branch type1 here
             break;
        case "type2":
             //create your branch type2 here
             break;
        case "type3":
             //create your branch type3 here
             break;
    }
}
```

Something like that.